# Kivy : how to add vertical scrollbar in boxlayout

Tags: python, python-2.7, kivy, kivy-language

I have written some code in Python (test.py) and kivy (test.kv).
 Can anyone tell me that How to add vertical scrollbar in my boxLayout?
I am using

ScrollView:
       do_scroll_y: True
       do_scroll_x: False
          BoxLayout:
                orientation: "vertical"

but I think maybe I'm making a mistake somewhere.
When i am using scrollView then design gets spoiled

## test.py

```
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window


Window.clearcolor = (0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1)
Window.size = (600, 700)

class ACgroup(Screen):
    pass


class TestACgroup(App):

    def build(self):
        self.root = Builder.load_file('test.kv')
        return self.root


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestACgroup().run()
```

## test.kv

```
<CustomLabel@Label>:
    text_size: self.size
    #padding_x: 5

<SingleLineTextInput@TextInput>:
    multiline: False


<GreenButton@Button>:
    background_color: 1, 1, 1, 1
    size_hint_y: None
    height: self.parent.height * 0.100

ACgroup:

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"

        GridLayout:
            cols: 2
            padding : 15, 15
            spacing: 20, 5
            row_default_height: '20dp'
            size_hint: 1, .01
            pos_hint: {'x': 0, 'y':.95}

            CustomLabel:
                text: 'Fname'
                text_size: self.size
                halign: 'left'
                valign: 'middle'
                size_hint_x: 2


            SingleLineTextInput:
                id: acGroup
                size_hint_x: 7


            Label:
                text: 'Name'
                text_size: self.size
                halign: 'left'
                valign: 'middle'
                size_hint_x: 2

            SingleLineTextInput:
                id: stateName

        GridLayout:
            cols: 4
            padding : 15, 10
            spacing: 20, 5
            row_default_height: '20dp'
            size_hint: 1, .01
            pos_hint: {'x': 0, 'y':.7}

            CustomLabel:
                text: 'ADDRESS :-'

            CustomLabel:

            CustomLabel:

            CustomLabel:

            CustomLabel:
                text: 'City'
                text_size: self.size
                halign: 'left'
                valign: 'middle'
                size_hint_x: 2

            SingleLineTextInput:
                id: acGroup
                size_hint_x: 4.5

            Label:
                text: 'Pin'
                text_size: self.size
                valign: 'middle'
                halign: 'right'


            SingleLineTextInput:
                id: stateCode

            CustomLabel:
                text: 'Area'
                text_size: self.size
                halign: 'left'
                valign: 'middle'
                size_hint_x: 2

            SingleLineTextInput:
                id: acGroup
                size_hint_x: 4.5

        GridLayout:

            cols: 6
            padding: 15, 15
            spacing: 5, 5
            row_default_height: '20dp'
            size_hint: 1, .005
            pos_hint: {'x': 0, 'y':.5}

            CustomLabel:
                text: 'Address'
                text_size: self.size
                halign: 'left'
                valign: 'middle'
                size_hint_x: 2
                #size_hint_y: 2

            SingleLineTextInput:
                id: acGroup
                size_hint_x: 3
                #size_hint_y: 2

            SingleLineTextInput:
                id: acGroup
                size_hint_x: 3
                #size_hint_y: 0

        GridLayout:
            cols: 2
            padding : 15, 5
            spacing: 10, 10
            row_default_height: '20dp'
            size_hint: 1, .02
            pos_hint: {'x': 0, 'y':.4}


            CustomLabel:
                text: 'CONTACT DETAIL:-'

            CustomLabel:

            Label:
                text: 'Phone'
                text_size: self.size
                halign: 'left'
                valign: 'middle'
                size_hint_x: 2

            SingleLineTextInput:
                id: acGroup
                size_hint_x: 6.5
                #size_hint_y: 2

            Label:
                text: 'Mobile'
                text_size: self.size
                halign: 'left'
                valign: 'middle'
                size_hint_x: 2

            SingleLineTextInput:
                id: acGroup
                size_hint_x: 6.5
                #size_hint_y: 2

            Label:
                text: 'E-Mail'
                text_size: self.size
                halign: 'left'
                valign: 'middle'
                size_hint_x: 2

            SingleLineTextInput:
                id: acGroup
                size_hint_x: 6.5
                #size_hint_y: 2


            GreenButton:
                text: 'Ok'


            GreenButton:
                text: 'Cancel'
                on_press: app.stop()
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you are using a vertical scrollview you must set the height of the only child like this:

```
ScrollView:
    BoxLayout:
        size_hint_y: None
        height: #the height that you want
```